# Maximizing a boolean function of AND and XOR on paritions of set

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, set

Given a set of distinct positive integers S we need to [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) a set in such a way that the following function is maximize. Let S<sub>1</sub>, S<sub>2</sub>, ... S<sub>n</sub> be the parition. n can be atleast 2.

F(S<sub>1</sub>, S<sub>2</sub>, ..., S<sub>n</sub>) = AND(XOR(S<sub>1</sub>), XOR(S<sub>2</sub>), ..., XOR(S<sub>n</sub>)))
where, AND is bitwise AND operation and XOR is bitwise XOR operation

We need to print the all such partitions possible.

I have tried the exponential approach as shown below.
I am looking for a solution with lesser complexity.

This problem is part of a homework, so only provide the hint.

```py
from functools import reduce
from collections import defaultdict

def partition(collection):
    if len(collection) == 1:
        yield [ collection ]
        return

    first = collection[0]
    for smaller in partition(collection[1:]):
        # insert `first` in each of the subpartition's subsets
        for n, subset in enumerate(smaller):
            yield smaller[:n] + [[ first ] + subset]  + smaller[n+1:]
        # put `first` in its own subset
        yield [ [ first ] ] + smaller
        # print("END OF THE LOOP")


x = 4
initialAssum = [2, 4, 8, 16]
something = initialAssum

def andxor(xs):
    def xorlist(xs):
        return reduce(lambda i, j: i ^ j, xs)

    tmp = [xorlist(x) for x in xs]

    return reduce(lambda i, j: i & j, tmp)

ans = defaultdict(list)
for n, p in enumerate(partition(something), 1):
    r = andxor(p)
    if len(p) > 1:
        ans[r].append(p)

m = max(ans.keys())
for a in ans[m]:
    print(a)
    #print(a, len(a))
print(f'{m}')
```

INPUT: the set itself
OUTPUT: max value possible followed by the all the partitions producing it

INPUT:

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

OUTPUT:

```
2  
[[4, 2], [3]]  
[[2], [4, 3]]
```

INPUT:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

OUTPUT:

```
0   
[[2], [4, 8, 16]]  
[[2, 4], [8, 16]]  
[[4], [2, 8, 16]]  
[[2], [4], [8, 16]]  
[[2, 4, 8], [16]]  
[[4, 8], [2, 16]]  
[[2], [4, 8], [16]]  
[[2, 8], [4, 16]]  
[[8], [2, 4, 16]]  
[[2], [8], [4, 16]]  
[[2, 4], [8], [16]]  
[[4], [2, 8], [16]]  
[[4], [8], [2, 16]]  
[[2], [4], [8], [16]]
```

Comment: I believe you can't really get better complexity. You may still have O(n!) possible partitions in the output.

Answer (score 0):

> This problem is part of a homework, so only provide the hint.

Hint: if we consider each bit separately from the highest to lowest, we can consider bit `k` as being set in the result if and only if that bit can appear an odd number of times in each part of the partition.

Comment: I have thought about that. But even after going through many examples, I was not able to construct an algorithm.